# format main.xml file

Tags: android

**Hello,**
i would like to know shortcut key to **format** my xml tag
for ex: (main.xml) when i drag and drop,code display in horizontal line like::

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart" android:orientation="horizontal" .. . . . . .... />
```

but i would like to know shoutcut , so i press it and display
like ::

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart" 
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            .. . . . . .... />
```

Thanks
nik

Comment: very good question for beginner.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+F if u use eclipse

Comment: please check pinki's answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so to select xml code or java code to format it properly. By simply pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+F` or `CTRL+I` you can properly reformat your code.

Press `CTRL+SHIFT+L` to shows all the command supported by Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

select the XML code that you want to format and press `CTRL+I`

Comment: @Chirag why did you commented with the existing answer?

Answer (score 3):

select the XML code that you want to format and press **`CTRL+SHIFT+F`**.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse:
If you want to set up formatting options - use menu Window->Preferences->XML->XML Files->Editor. But before make sure that "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" are installed (as plugin which is a part of WST (subproject of [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)))